# how to change zsh terminal line width on 'mac os catalina 10.15.6'

Tags: c, macos

how do i increase the number of characters a mac terminal line can display?

for instance the following code is supposed to print the entire str but it only prints the last 91 characters. i'd like to increase the limit to about 500 characters. any advice ?

Thanks in advance :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "string test *******************************************************************************************";
    int length = 0;

    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
        length++;

    fprintf(stdout, "str:\n%s\n\n", str);

    fprintf(stdout, "length = %d\n", length);

    return 0;
}
```